# mongoose how to manage count in a reference document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So I've got these schemas:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/**
 * Comment Schema
 */
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    post_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post',
        required: true
    },
    author:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'pending'
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    },
    meta: {
        votes: Number
    }
});

/**
 * Validations
 */
CommentSchema.path('author').validate(function(author) {
    return author.length;
}, 'Author cannot be empty');

CommentSchema.path('email').validate(function(email) {
    return email.length;
}, 'Email cannot be empty');

CommentSchema.path('email').validate(function(email) {
    var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    return emailRegex.test(email);
}, 'The email is not a valid email');

CommentSchema.path('body').validate(function(body) {
    return body.length;
}, 'Body cannot be empty');

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    monguurl = require('monguurl'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


/**
 * Article Schema
 */
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    author:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'whisher'
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    },
    published: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    categories: {
        type: [String], 
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    tags: {
        type: [String], 
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'CommentSchema'
    },
    meta: {
        votes: Number
    }
});

/**
 * Validations
 */
PostSchema.path('title').validate(function(title) {
    return title.length;
}, 'Title cannot be empty');

PostSchema.path('body').validate(function(body) {
    return body.length;
}, 'Body cannot be empty');

PostSchema.path('status').validate(function(status) {
    return /publish|draft/.test(status);
}, 'Is not a valid status');

PostSchema.plugin(monguurl({
  source: 'title',
  target: 'slug'
}));

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

by an api I query Post like

```
exports.all = function(req, res) {
    Post.find().sort('-created').exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
           res.jsonp(500,{ error: err.message });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(200,posts);
        }
    });
};
```

How to retrieve how many comments has the post ?
I mean I want an extra propriety in post object
like post.ncomments.

The first thing I think of is adding an extra
field to the post schema and update it whenever a user 
add a comment

```
meta: {
    votes: Number,
    ncomments:Number
}
```

but it seems quite ugly I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the likely the most efficient solution, then manually adding a field like `number_comments` to the `Post` schema may be the best way to go, especially if you want to do things like act on multiple posts (like sorting based on comments). Even if you used an index to do the count, it's not likely to be as efficient as having the count pre-calculated (and ultimately, there are just more types of queries you can perform when it has been pre-calculated, if you haven't chosen to embed the comments).

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    /* others */
    number_comments: {
        type: Number
    } 
});
```

To update the number:

```
Post.update({ _id : myPostId}, {$inc: {number_comments: 1}}, /* callback */);
```

Also, you won't need a `comment` field in the `PostSchema` unless you're using it as a "most recent" style field (or some other way where there'd only be one). The fact that you have a `Post` reference in the `Comment` schema would be sufficient to find all `Comment`s for a given `Post`:

```
Comments.find().where("post_id", myPostId).exec(/* callback */);
```

You'd want to make sure that the field is indexed. As you can use `populate` with this as you've specified the `ref` for the field, you might consider renaming the field to `"post"`.

```
Comments.find().where("post", myPostId).exec(/* callback */);
```

You'd still only set the `post` field to the `_id` of the `Post` though (and not an actual `Post` object instance).

You could also choose to embed the comments in the `Post`. There's some [good information](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) on the MongoDB web site about these choices. Note that even if you embedded the comments, you'd need to bring back the entire array just to get the count.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `Post` schema will only allow for a single comment:

```
// ....
comment: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'CommentSchema'
},
// ....
```

One consideration is to just store your comments as subdocuments on your posts rather than in their own collection.  Will you in general be querying your comments only as they related to their relevant post, or will you frequently be looking at all comments independent of their post?

If you move the comments to subdocuments, then you'll be able to do something like `post.comments.length`.

However, if you retain comments as a separate collection (relational structure in a NoSQL DB-- there are sometimes reasons to do this), there isn't an automatic way of doing this.  Mongo can't do joins, so you'll have to issue a second query.  You have a few options in how to do that.  One is an instance method on your post instances.  You could also just do a manual `CommentSchema.count({postId: <>})`.

Your proposed solution is perfectly valid too.  That strategy is used in relational databases that *can* do joins, because it would have better performances than counting up all the comments each time.

Comment: [It looks like your Post schema will only allow for a single comment] I followed http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html and I thought in that way to have more comments for a post. So can you update your reply with an example, please ?

Comment: [One consideration is to just store your comments as subdocuments on your posts rather than in their own collection. Will you in general be querying your comments only as they related to their relevant post, or will you frequently be looking at all comments independent of their post?] the only thing I've used a reference to a subdocuments is to allow user to vote the comment and for the status  and without _id it's quite tricky imo but you are free to show me an other approach :)

Comment: I tested and the code add more than one db.comments.find({post_id:ObjectId('52e6765f3e6ad8dd1d6d1aec')}).count() give me 2